# ComboBox.SelectedValue not updating from binding source

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, combobox

Here's my binding source object:

```
Public Class MyListObject

    Private _mylist As New ObservableCollection(Of String)
    Private _selectedName As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal nameList As List(Of String), ByVal defaultName As String)

        For Each name In nameList
            _mylist.Add(name)
        Next

        _selectedName = defaultName

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property MyList() As ObservableCollection(Of String)
        Get
            Return _mylist
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SelectedName() As String
        Get
            Return _selectedName
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyListObject" ObjectInstance="" />
    </Window.Resources>

        <Grid>

        <ComboBox Height="23"
                  Margin="24,91,53,0"
                  Name="ComboBox1"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedName, Source={StaticResource MyListObject}, Mode=OneWay}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList, Source={StaticResource MyListObject}, Mode=OneWay}"
                  />

        <Button Height="23"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="47,0,0,87"
                Name="btn_List1"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Width="75">List 1</Button>

        <Button Height="23"
                Margin="0,0,75,87"
                Name="btn_List2"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Width="75">List 2</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the code-behind:

```
Class Window1

    Private obj1 As MyListObject
    Private obj2 As MyListObject
    Private odp As ObjectDataProvider

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        Dim namelist1 As New List(Of String)
        namelist1.Add("Joe")
        namelist1.Add("Steve")
        obj1 = New MyListObject(namelist1, "Steve")
.
        Dim namelist2 As New List(Of String)
        namelist2.Add("Bob")
        namelist2.Add("Tim")
        obj2 = New MyListObject(namelist2, "Tim")

        odp = DirectCast(Me.FindResource("MyListObject"), ObjectDataProvider)
        odp.ObjectInstance = obj1

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_List1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn_List1.Click

        odp.ObjectInstance = obj1

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_List2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn_List2.Click

        odp.ObjectInstance = obj2

    End Sub
End Class
```

When the Window first loads, the bindings hook up fine.  The ComboBox contains the names "Joe" and "Steve" and "Steve" is selected by default.  However, when I click a button to switch the ObjectInstance to obj2, the ComboBox ItemsSource gets populated correctly in the dropdown, but the SelectedValue is set to Nothing instead of being equal to obj2.SelectedName.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We had a similar issue last week.  It has to do with how `SelectedValue` updates its internals. What we found was if you set `SelectedValue` it would not see the change we had to instead set `SelectedItem` which would properly update every thing.  My conclusion is that `SelectedValue` is **designed for get** operations and **not set**.  But this may just be a bug in the current version of 3.5sp1 .net

Comment: Confirming this issue is still present in .NET 4...best to just rely on `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`

Comment: I am currently having issues with `SelectedValue` in .NET 4.5... For me `SelectedItem` too solves the issue.

Comment: I have a similar issue which seems to be acting oppositely from what your describing , where i am using only SelectedItem 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300281/combobox-selectedvalue-not-changing-from-binding-to-dependency-property#22300281

Comment: This answer solves the issue (`SelectedItem` actually does what both of these guys seem to have thought `SelectedValue` was supposed to do), but it's mistaken about the cause of the problem. The problem was that [`SelectedValue` needs `SelectedValuePath`. This is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx). `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` do different things.

Comment: I managed to solve this in my case by adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the `SelectedValue` binding. To me it feels like a special kind of ridiculous that I had to set that value at all.

Answer (score 16):

To stir up a 2 year old conversation:

Another possibility, if you're wanting to use strings, is to bind it to the Text property of the combobox.

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding Test}">
     <ComboBoxItem Content="A" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="B" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="C" />
</ComboBox>
```

That's bound to something like:

```
public class TestCode
{
    private string _test;
    public string Test 
    { 
      get { return _test; }
      set
      {
         _test = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Test); // NotifyPropertyChanged("Test"); if not using Caliburn
      }
    }
}
```

The above code is Two-Way so if you set Test="B"; in code then the combobox will show 'B', and then if you select 'A' from the drop down then the bound property will reflect the change.

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

in the binding

Comment: <code>Mode=TwoWay</code>, and UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged must be set explicitly. Don't confuse them defaults.

Comment: not always works , for example when binding a class 's property.
When you change the property the value not updated

Answer (score 6):

The type of the `SelectedValuePath` and the `SelectedValue` must be EXACTLY the same.

If for example the type of `SelectedValuePath` is `Int16` and the type of the property that binds to `SelectedValue` is `int` it will not work.

I spend hours to find that, and that's why I am answering here after so much time the question was asked. Maybe another poor guy like me with the same problem can see it.

Comment: Yes, there *was* another poor guy like you. Also `Int16` vs `int` problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

Problem:

The ComboBox class searches for the specified object by using the IndexOf method. This method uses the Equals method to determine equality.

Solution:

So, try to set SelectedIndex using SelectedValue via Converter like this:

**C# code**

```
//Converter

public class SelectedToIndexConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value is YourType)
            {
                YourType YourSelectedValue = (YourType) value;

                YourSelectedValue = (YourType) cmbDowntimeDictionary.Tag;
                YourType a = (from dd in Helper.YourType
                                        where dd.YourTypePrimaryKey == YourSelectedValue.YourTypePrimaryKey
                                        select dd).First();

                int index = YourTypeCollection.IndexOf(a); //YourTypeCollection - Same as ItemsSource of ComboBox
            }
            return null;
        }
         public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value!=null && value is int)
            {
                return YourTypeCollection[(int) value];
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Xaml**

```xml
<ComboBox 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource YourDataProvider}}"
   SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=YourValue, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource SelectedToIndexConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3):

Ran into something similar, finally I just subscribed to the SelectionChanged event for the drop down and set my data property with it.  Silly and wish it was not needed, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is it reasonable to set the `SelectedValuePath="Content"` in the combobox's xaml, and then use `SelectedValue` as the binding?

It appears that you have a list of strings and want the binding to just do string matching against the actual item content in the combobox, so if you tell it which property to use for the `SelectedValue` it should work; at least, that worked for me when I ran across this problem.

It seems like Content would be a sensible default for `SelectedValue` but perhaps it isn't?

Comment: Thank you this pointed me in the right direction. I wanted the Name property of the ComboBoxItem so I set the SelectedValuePath="Name" and it works like a champ

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried raising an event that signals SelectName has been updated, e.g., OnPropertyChanged("SelectedName")? That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was binding to a list while I should be binding to a string.

**What I was doing:**

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _SelectedPartyType;

public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedPartyType { get { return 
_SelectedPartyType; } set { 
             _SelectedPartyType = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPartyType"); } }
```

**What should be**

```
 private string _SelectedPartyType;

 public string SelectedPartyType { get { return _SelectedPartyType; } set { 
             _SelectedPartyType = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPartyType"); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Binding Mode needs to be OneWayToSource or TwoWay since the source is what you want updated. Mode OneWay is Source to Target and therefore makes the Source ReadOnly which results in never updating the Source.

Answer (score 0):

You know...  I've been fighting with this issue for hours today, and you know what I found out?  It was a DataType issue!  The list that was populating the ComboBox was Int64, and I was trying to store the value in an Int32 field!  No errors were being thrown, it just wasn't storing the values!

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved this. Huh!!!
Either use [one of...] .SelectedValue | .SelectedItem | .SelectedText
Tip: Selected Value is preferred for ComboStyle.DropDownList while .SelectedText is for ComboStyle.DropDown.

-This should solve your problem. took me more than a week to resolve this small fyn. hah!!

Comment: Please use either ONE of them and NOT both or all 3