# Do WPF ComboBox SelectedIndex and SelectedValue have different behavior on SelectionChanged event?

Tags: wpf, combobox, selectedvalue, selectedindex, selectionchanged

I got this cbxJobPosition_SelectionChanged firing as expected. The problem is when a external method tries to set *cbxJobPosition*.

cbxJobPosition is databinded with a list of objects of type *JobPosition*:

- JobPositionID: 1, JobPositionName: Manager
- JobPositionID: 2, JobPositionName: Employee
- JobPositionID: 3, JobPositionName: Third party

Here's the XAML:

```
<ComboBox Cursor="Hand" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
FontSize="13" Name="cbxJobPosition"     
SelectedValuePath="JobPositionID" DisplayMemberPath="JobPositionName" 
SelectedIndex="0" Width="233" Height="23" 
SelectionChanged="cbxJobPosition_SelectionChanged" />
```

On UserControl_Loaded method, it reads from database the list of jobs and try to set the specific job position "Third party":

```
//calls cbxJobPosition_SelectionChanged and passes the correct SelectedValue within
cbxJobPosition.SelectedIndex = 3;

//calls cbxJobPosition_SelectionChanged and but won't pass the correct SelectedValue within
cbxJobPosition.SelectedValue = "3";
```

As you can notice, when the processing is automatically redirected to cbxJobPosition_SelectionChanged, the SelectedValue attribute will have different values for each statement above when you're debugging within cbxJobPosition_SelectionChanged event.

Does anyone know if this difference is expected, am I missing something or it could be a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is JobPositionID a `string`? If not, that could explain why it doesn't work. At the databinding level, WPF won't automatically convert `string` to `int`. I'm guessing it changes the selection on the box to none when you attempt it.

Comment: I came up with searching the element with LINQ and setting combobox's SelectedItem with the found object and executing SelectionChanged statements (on an external method). I may say that I don't like this solution.

Comment: Well I don't know all the details of what you're doing, but at least for the example, you could parse "3" into an int, then use it to set SelectedValue.

Comment: Yes. I pass an int like 3 to cbxJobPosition.SelectedValue = 3; when redirected to cbxJobPosition_SelectionChanged, cbxJobPosition.SelectedValue is null! Quite wierd!

Comment: (e.Source as ComboBox) and (e.OriginalSource as ComboBox).SelectedValue are also null

Comment: Oh, my bad. Passing in "3" as a string should work just fine. Looks like you're running into this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247413/wpf-combobox-selectedvalue-not-updating-from-binding-source . In short, SelectedValue only works well for get operations, not set.