# Binding ComboBox twoway mode isn't working?

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, binding-mode

what I understand from this term "TwoWay" is that if any value at one end changes , it should directly get reflected to the other end, for example I have this ComboBox

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding CarModel,Mode=TwoWay,IsAsync=True}" ItemsSource="{Binding carModelNames}" />
```

now I wanted the SelectedValue to be nothing/null, I just updated my CarModel property in the code/viewModel to be "", but that didn't work, am I missing something here ??

here is my property

```
public String CarModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _CarModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_CarModel != value)
            {
                _CarModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CarModel");
            }

        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: What is the type of CarModel?

Answer (score 4):

look here [ComboBox.SelectedValue not updating from binding source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247413/wpf-combobox-selectedvalue-not-updating-from-binding-source/247482#247482)

you can use `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` instead

Answer (score 2):

If the SelectedValue is changed in Code, the Control only updates, if the new value is contained in the ItemsSource. So the Collection of carModelNames must contain string.Empty or it would not be a valid Selection.

Answer (score 0):

The propert carModelNames should be of type collection you are binding to combobox..And must use OnPropertyChange in the setter... And it would be better to use seletedItem instead of selected value..

Comment: carModelNames is an ObservableCollection<String> , I changed it to SelectedItem , see my edit on the first post to see the property I'm binding to

Comment: @Musab: Your property name is GlassType and and the selected value property u gave in xaml is CarModel it should be GlassType....

Comment: yeah , I just copied  the wrong property, going to fix that in a second , it could be considered a typo error

Comment: NO , I had to changed my strategy , but I've got to tell you, these 4.0 ComboBox has serious issues and very buggy