# WPF ComboBox.SelectedValue is null but .SelectedItem is not; SelectedValuePath is set. Why?

Tags: wpf, combobox, .net-4.0

Debugging a strange NullRefException i see the following picture:

[image: Double-shot to display .SelectedItem]

So when the code is referring to `.SelectedValue` it crashes.

I cannot understand how `.SelectedItem` can be set, but `.SelectedValue` not.  Values displayed in debugger's viewer are correct, `.SelectedIndex` is appropriate also.  ComboBox's `.ItemsSource` is set to a `List<DvcTypes>` in code:

```
cbAdmDvc.ItemsSource =  J790M.DAL.DvcTypes.GetList( );
```

`.SelectedValuePath` is set in XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbAdmDvc" DisplayMemberPath="sDvcType"
  SelectedValuePath="tiDvcType" SelectionChanged="cbAdmDvc_SelectionChanged".. />
```

Drop-down portion is properly displaying `.sDvcType` labels later on.
Very much the same implementation works for a bunch of other filtering combo-boxes (7 more).
This is happening during Loaded event for the main window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far i cannot explain the observed behavior, but found a relatively simple workaround:

```
private void    cbAdmDvc_SelectionChanged( object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e )
{
    if(  cbAdmDvc.SelectedIndex < 0  )  return;

    DvcType tiDvc;      /// add this temp variable to capture .SelectedValue

    if(  cbAdmDvc.SelectedValue != null  )
        tiDvc=  (DvcType) cbAdmDvc.SelectedValue;
    else
        tiDvc=  ((DvcTypes) cbAdmDvc.SelectedItem).tiDvcType;

    DoSmth( tiDvc );    /// instead of DoSmth( (DvcType)cbAdmDvc.SelectedValue )
}
```

Silly, but it works, since `.SelectedItem` is set properly.
As i said before, this is the only ComboBox experiencing such oddities out of several..

**EDIT, 2014-Oct-21**:

After making some changes in the application logic surprisingly found myself looking at the same issue with another ComboBox.  Found a potential solution [combobox-selectedvalue-not-updating-from-binding-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247413/), but when i tried setting initial values via `.SelectedItem` instead of `.SelectedValue` things got even weirder/worse.  So i tried to apply my previous solution here as well and it worked!

*Here's my attempt to explain the observed behavior*:
Setting an initial value in code (`CBox.SelectedValue= smth;`) triggers `CBox_SelectionChanged` event.  For some reason at that moment reading `.SelectedValue` returns null (as if it's not ready yet), however reading `.SelectedItem` seems to work fine!  Once you're out of `CBox_SelectionChanged` event code can read `.SelectedValue` properly..

So, if you **1**) have a handler for `_SelectionChanged` event, **2**) refer to `.SelectedValue` within it, and **3**) are setting initial choice via `.SelectedValue` somewhere else in code - watch out for `null` and code defensively!  HTH!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just came around the same annoying issue. After looking at the Reference Source of .NET Framework I've found some hints that in previous versions the `SelectedValue` property sometimes was not updated before the `SelectionChanged` event raises. Microsoft has fixed this "bug" with the release of .NET 4.7.1.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.7-4.7.1#selector-selectionchanged-event-and-selectedvalue-property